# Database update committed despite BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK

Tags: abap

I have a `Modify` statement to update a custom table after which I am calling `BAPI_CONTRACT_CHANGE`. When BAPI failed to change the document it's calling `BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK`. However, it's not changing the data back in my custom table which was updated by `Modify` statement.

```
  IF gt_return[] IS NOT INITIAL.
    READ TABLE gt_return INTO gwa_return WITH KEY type = 'E'.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK'.
      MESSAGE i021(zxx).
    ELSE.
      CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
        EXPORTING
          wait = abap_true.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
```

Appreciate  your response.

Modify statement is present somewhere before the bapi call.and also this program can be run from external portal . The behaviour is as expected when I run it from the portal i.e, BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK works and data doesn't get updated in the custom table. It fails only when I run it from ECC.

Comment: The only reason is that there was a database commit before the rollback. You need to do a SQL trace (`ST05` for instance) to locate this database commit. Notice that any dialog displayed triggers an implicit database commit.

Comment: you didn't show your MODIFY statement in your code

Comment: The first thing `BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK` does is execute a `ROLLBACK WORK` command. So it appears that there is some `COMMIT WORK` happening somewhere between your `MODIFY` and the `BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK`. I would set a debugger breakpoint on the `COMMIT WORK` command and see if one happens somewhere where I would not expect it. But there are also a couple other situations which cause an implicit database commit. Some examples are listed [in this blog post](https://www.trailsap.com/sap-help/?topic=db_commit)

Answer (score 0):

You get an implicit commit on each PBO screen interaction.
So any user interaction after the Insert/modify/update DB will be committed without code needing to issuing a commit work.
if you want to rollback , it must be done before the next PBO cycle.